# How send alert to special external form with zabbix?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I want to create media types or script to send alerts to external form and submit the form with zabbix ?

version zabbix 5.0

Answer (score 1):

You can call any external URl with parameters using a [WebHook](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/notifications/media/webhook): there are lots of existing integrations or you can write your own.

You can't compile and submit a form directly: you should analyze the form to find out the called URL and parameters, manage authentication etc., then implement your webhook.

As a last resort, which I do not recommend, you can write an external script with
[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/) or similar tools to open a headless browser, follow the XPaths to the fields, compile them and finally submit the form.